# Migrating machine Certificates generated by docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I've generated a swarm cluster using docker-machine on my local machine and want to be able to deploy containers to the swarm from a different host.

The problem is I can't figure out which certificates to use or whether or not I am linking them correctly.

All attempts I have made have resulted in

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority...
```

Must I generate new certificates on each host I want to give access to?

I have tried copying my certs from `~/.docker/machine/certs` and the `.config` file from "`~/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master`" but `docker-machine` and `docker` yell at me whenever I try using them.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have certificates issues (as in: they are not properly installed), you can report to the [Install registry certificates on client Docker daemons](https://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/configure/config-security/#install-registry-certificates-on-client-docker-daemons).

It is about the docker registry, but applies also to any certificate you might have to install on a docker machine (be it a boot2docker one, or a regular Ubuntu or RHEL/Centos server.

In the host missing the certificate, try an `openssl s_client -connect` command to get said certificate, as I do in [this script `add_reg_crt.sh`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/bf94e41e909cc6d2e93b9f51991d997ad1448e38/scripts/add_reg_crt.sh), with  "that other host" being a boot2docker one:

```sh
if [[ ! -e /var/lib/boot2docker/registry.crt ]]; then
    openssl s_client -connect kv:5000 -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM | sudo tee /var/lib/boot2docker/registry.crt
fi
rline=$(tail -2 /var/lib/boot2docker/registry.crt | head -1)
if [[ "$(grep ${rline} /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt)" == "" ]]; then
    cat /var/lib/boot2docker/registry.crt | sudo tee -a /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote little node utility for importing and exporting the docker machine certs needed for connecting to them https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mumbacloud/dmport this returns json with the certs embedded

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.